# Getting Location Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, location

I am developing an app that gets the user's location.

It works fine.

The issue is that I have a memory leak.
I am not exactly sure why and I think it's from the Location Services but I am not sure.

I have added Leak Canary to my app and it has shown me that I have a 74 mb leak from: android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.mListener

Other times it is from com.edon.freiner.siddur.MainActivity$26.this$0  //that is my app 
(anonymous implementation of android.locaition.LocationListener)

I am not sure where to look in my app because I commented out all my Location code to see if there was a change in the memory graph in Android Studio, I could not find any changes.

Here is my code:

```
 public void startLocation() {

    Log.d("Start Location", " Started");

    LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

            DataVariables.getInstance().setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            DataVariables.getInstance().setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();


            Log.d("Loc Manager latitude", "`" + location.getLatitude());
            Log.d("Loc Manager longitude", "`" + location.getLongitude());

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000,
                    1000, mLocationListener);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you call `removeLocationUpdates()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare where would I put that? Thanks

Comment: `onDestroy()`, if not sooner. That's really up to you. Only request locations when you need them. The sooner you stop, the less power you drain.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added it here  if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000,
                        1000, mLocationListener);
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);

            } But I see no difference in the memory. I only need the location once to display it to the user. Once I am done with the I do not need to get it again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `requestSingleUpdate()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, I will try that, what is a looper? it says Looper: a Looper object whose message queue will be used to implement the callback mechanism, or null to make callbacks on the calling thread. what does that mean? Thanks

Comment: If you want to be called on the main application thread, pass in `Looper.getMainLooper()`. Otherwise, create a `HandlerThread`, and use its `getLooper()` method.

Comment: Ok, so far I have this if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                mLocationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, mLocationListener, Looper.getMainLooper());
            }
        }
I am still getting a memory leak. Am I implementing it wrong?

Comment: @CommonsWare^^^ Thanks

Comment: That seems OK. Your `SystemSensorManager` issue would seem to be tied to something other than the `LocationListener` and the code in your question, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare What do you mean? I have another SystemSensorManager, but not in the location, I use a compass as well. I use a SystemSensor for that

Comment: I commented out all of my code except the layout and it seems that it is taking up 89mb and only 15mb free. I checked the images, that was my first hunch, they are all very low and shouldn't make a fuss. Not sure what else it could be.

Comment: Your question states that you have two leaks. One was tied to locations, which is what most of your question is about and what this looooooooooooooong comment chain is about. You also have `android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.mListener`. That is not tied to locations. If you are using `SensorManager`, make sure that you unregister your sensor listener when you no longer need the sensor readings.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it I found the issue. It was one of my images